# Select no cambia de opcion

Tags: php, jquery

tengo un Select que cargo de manera dinamica por medio de ajax:

**Html**

```
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="form-label">Sector: </label>
      <select name="idSector" id="idSector" class="form-control" onchange="buscarEstacionesSector(this.value);"> 
      </select>
    </div>
```

**JS**

```
  $.ajax({
    type : 'post',
    url  : "<?php echo site_url('Sectores/buscarSectoresCae'); ?>",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
      idCae   : idCae
    },
  }).done( function(data) {
    if($("#modalParte").is(':visible')){

      $('#modalParte #idSector').find('option').remove();
        $('#modalParte #idSector').append('<option value="">SELECCIONE...</option');
      $(data).each(function(i, v){
        $('#modalParte #idSector').append('<option value="'+ v.idSector +'">' + v.nombreSector+ '</option');
      })   
    }else{
      $('#modalActualizarParte #idSector').find('option').remove();
        $('#modalActualizarParte #idSector').append('<option value="">SELECCIONE...</option');
      $(data).each(function(i, v){
        $('#modalActualizarParte #idSector').append('<option value="'+ v.idSector +'">' + v.nombreSector+ '</option');
      })  

    }
  }).fail( function() {
    swal("Información!", "No se pudierson cargar los sectores", "warning"); 
  }).always( function() {
    //alert( 'Always' );
  });
```

El mismo carga bien, la cuestion es al tratar de establecer un valor al select "**idSector**" no se cambia siempre se mantiene en "**SELECCIONE...**"

Con lo que trato de cambiar de valor es:

```
$("#modalActualizarParte #idSector").val(data[0].sector_id);
```

al verificar el valor de data[0].sector_id por consola es "6" el cual en las opciones del select si consta no entiendo el porque no se cambia de valor.

gracias cualquier sugerencia.

Comment: No estás cerrando los option, todos terminan en `</option` te falta `>` al final.

Comment: Gracias ya cambie esa parte, pero aun persiste el problema ..!!

Comment: Será que al actualizar usas `.sector_id` y al generar las opciones tienes `.idSector`, supongo que en la consola debería aparecer un error si este es el caso.